# How to transfer data to another jsp

Tags: java, javascript

I've built a dynamic table that has an add button (that adds a new row), delete button (deletes rows) and submit.

I wanna take all the information in the table (I don't know how many rows the user will add) and process it at other jsp page.

This is what I have so far:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
                var cb=new Array();
                var fn=new Array();
                var ln=new Array();
                var email=new Array();
                var i=1;
                function addRow(tableId){
                    var table=document.getElementById(tableId);

                    var rowCount=table.rows.length;
                    var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);

                    var cell= row.insertCell(0);
                    var element=document.createElement("input");
                    element.type="checkBox";
                    element.name="cb"+i+"";
                    cell.appendChild(element);

                    var cell1=row.insertCell(1);
                    cell1.innerHTML=rowCount;

                    var cell2=row.insertCell(2);
                    var element2=document.createElement("input");
                    element2.type="text";
                    element2.name="fn"+i+"";
                    cell2.appendChild(element2);

                    var cell3=row.insertCell(3);
                    var element3=document.createElement("input");
                    element3.type="text";
                    element3.name="ln"+i+"";
                    cell3.appendChild(element3);

                    var cell4=row.insertCell(4);
                    var element4=document.createElement("input");
                    element4.type="email";
                    element4.name="email"+i+"";
                    cell4.appendChild(element4);

                    i++;
                }
                function delRow(tableId){
                    var table=document.getElementById(tableId);
                    var rowCount=table.rows.length;
                    for(i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
                        var row=table.rows[i];
                        var chkbox=row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                        if(chkbox!==null && chkbox.checked===true)
                            {
                                table.deleteRow(i);
                                rowCount--;
                                i--;
                                for(var k=1;k<rowCount;k++){
                                    var row=table.rows[k];
                                    var cell=row.cells[1];
                                    cell.innerHTML=k;
                                                           }
                           }
                    }
                 }
                function valCk(){

                }



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" action="dataShow.jsp"  method="get">
            <input type='button' value="Add" onclick="addRow('tableData');">
            <input type='button' value="delete" onclick="delRow('tableData');">
            <input type='submit' value="submit" onclick="valCk()">
        <table id="tableData" border="3">
                <tr><td>chack</td><td>#</td><td>First name</td><td>Last name</td><td>Email</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='cb0'></td><td>1</td><td><input type='text' name="fn0"><td><input type="text" name="ln0"></td><td><input type="email" name="email0"></td></tr>
       </table>        
       </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

as you can see I have an array for every field. I think that if I put all the data in arrays and send it with query string it will be just fine but not :/
For example, this is the query for 3 line table

The jsp code is:

```
<%  
    String rows=request.getParameter("row");
    int foo = Integer.parseInt("rows");
    for(int i=0;i<=foo;i++){
        user u =new user();
        u.fn=request.getParameter("fn[i]");
        u.ln=request.getParameter("ln0[i]");
        u.email=request.getParameter("email[i]");

    }
      %>
```

I get a 500 error.

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /dataShow.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable fn
  location: class org.apache.jsp.dataShow_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /dataShow.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
no suitable method found for print()
    method javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print(java.lang.Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print(char[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print(double) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print(float) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print(long) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print(char) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter.print(boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

Comment: Try setting the data in session and then fetch it in the second jsp.

Comment: 500 means that an exception is been thrown which usually contains a waelth of information about the cause and the path to the problem (and inherently thus also the whole answer to the problem). Why are you ignoring it as if it's irrelevant information? If you're unable to interpret exceptions, then you should not ignore them as if they're decoration, instead you should post a question with a copypaste of the entire stacktrace included.

Comment: By the way, I *guess* that it's a very simple `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "rows"` which is self-explaining enough and in no way related to JSP, Servlets, let alone JavaScript.

Comment: OTOH, using exceptions as a source for generative art does have a certain appeal.

Comment: obviously `Integer.parseInt("rows");` is wrong: the String `"rows"` does not represent an integer value, it should be `Integer.parseInt(rows);`

Comment: i add the 500 error... i still dont have a clue how to do it.. how can I take the fn[] array to the other jsp?

Comment: Why are you processing the request in a JSP! You could really benefit from an MVC framework but at the least logic like this should be in a servlet/service called from a servlet. Keep the JSP purely for rendering the view.

Comment: Also, if you're building up rows on the web page and passing this back to the server you might want to look at a JS framework like knockout.